# Avoid unnecessary update in "update or insert" SQL?

Tags: sql, firebird

Here is Firebird SQL description for update or insert:

https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-update-or-insert.html

And my example

```
update or insert into books (id, name)
  values (555, 'Good book')
  matching (id)
```

If book already exists with `id=555` and `name='Good book'` then this command executes update statement anyway and the triggering of update triggers is the only effect of such update, no change of the values for the record. Is it possible to request in this SQL that there is not need to execute update, if the updatable fields (e.g. name in this case) have the specified values already.

My question is for Firebird 2, 3, 4. But if there is similar preventing clause in SQL server, MySQL or Oracle, then I would be happy to hear.

Comment: `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that would deny update?

Comment: I am not sure that Firebird has such deny feature. And it would be better to avoid even the initialisation of the update command, it is waste of resources.

Comment: Then I guess there's no such feature, except if your RDBMS already optimizes the waste of resources and trigering is the only side effect. I'm positively inclined that some optimizations are always implicitly applied, e.g. pending changes are cached somewhere in RAM outside the DB and then flushed on the disk once in a while. But to be sure you should be a guru of a particular RDBMS

Comment: use `merge` command instead of U-or-I then. However if all you need is single row then a redundant update is not a problem. If you have many rows then they either already are stored in some table, or can be inserted into a GTT (global temporary table) before. And after you did it - run `merge`

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov There is no optimization, because Firebird uses MVCC, and an update will write a new record version, and this record version needs to exist for certain pessimistic locking algorithms to work (no-op updates are sometimes used exactly for this purpose, so they can't be optimized away)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the update, then you should not use [`UPDATE OR INSERT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-update-or-insert), but instead use [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-merge), or use [`INSERT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-insert) and catch and ignore the duplicate key error (assuming you have a suitable primary or unique key constraint).

Example of using `MERGE`:

```sql
merge into books 
using (
  select 555 as id, 'Good book' as name
  from rdb$database) as src
on books.id = src.id
when not matched then
  insert (id, name) values (src.id, src.name)
```